# How to catch telnet disconnection (Delphi Indy telnet)?

Tags: delphi, telnet, indy

I'm using Indy telnet client component in Delphi program.
Now i need to catch telnet disconnection (for example when some other program connect to the same host my connection broke).
How to catch it?

Comment: To check if the connection is still writeable, you may send a NOP command from your client (see RFC 854 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You can use the `OnStatus` event, checking for the `hsDisconnected` status.</strike>

At this time, `TIdTelnet` does not trigger either the `OnDisconnect` or `OnStatus` event when the connection is closed unexpectedly. This is a known issue that has an open ticket in Indy's issue tracker:

[#118: TIdTelnet needs to trigger OnDisconnect or OnStatus when disconnected](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/118)

Until this is fixed, you would have to modify `TIdTelnet`'s source code to hook into its internal reading thread, or at least assign on `OnTerminate` handler to it, to detect when it stops running.

Comment: I had try this alredy. No success. Because it is not normal disconnection, it's like error disconnection.

Comment: @Supply it should be during the `OnStatus` event whether the connection is closed gracefully or lost abnormally. If it is not, I'll have to look into that

Comment: When connection close gracefully (another app connected on the same telnet port) my app show Exception Socket error 10054 Connection reset by peer. I had add this code:    <code>procedure TForm1.IdTelnet1Status(ASender: TObject; const AStatus: TIdStatus;
  const AStatusText: string);
begin
if AStatus = hsDisconnected then
Begin
  try
    if idtelnet1.Connected = False then
      idtelnet1.Connect
  Except

  end;
End;</code>  no reaction

Comment: @Supply that is not a graceful disconnect, and the exception is expected, but I would have expected Indy to report it better. Like I said, I'll have to look into it.